# How can I add simple up/down movement on the Y-axis to an enemy that has velocity on the X-axis attached to it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a 2D horizontal side-scroller and I have enemies being spawned whose rigidbody component is being used to give them a velocity like so:

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 public class Mover : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public new Rigidbody2D rigidbody;
    public bool random;

    void Start()
    {
       if (random) {
        rigidbody.velocity = Random.value * transform.right * speed;
    }
  else
    {
        rigidbody.velocity = transform.right * speed;
    }
    }
}
```

How can I have these enemies also move up and down constantly on the the Y-axis while they are moving with a velocity on the X-axis? Everything I have tried seems to interfere with the velocity of the objects. I am basically trying to create a simple behavioral pattern so as to make the targets harder for the player to aim at.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution by following the answer given under this link: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/96878/how-to-animate-objects-with-bobbing-up-and-down-motion-in-unity?newreg=ccb2eaf1b725413ca777a68348637990

Here is my updated code:

```
public class EnemyMover : MonoBehaviour {
public float speed;
public new Rigidbody2D rigidbody;
public bool random;
float originalY;

public float floatStrength = 1;  

void Start()
{
    this.originalY = this.transform.position.y;

     if (random) {
          rigidbody.velocity = Random.value * transform.right * speed;
      }else
      {
        rigidbody.velocity = transform.right * speed;
    }


}


void Update()
{
    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x,
           originalY + ((float)System.Math.Sin(Time.time) * floatStrength),
           transform.position.z);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a starting point, but you would have to experiment with different ways to do it to get the behavior you want. Maybe you can try using `rigidbody.AddForce` too.

If you haven't already, I recommend watching the video [tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials) for the 2D platformer.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
public class Mover : MonoBehaviour {
  public float speed, waveSpeed;
  new Rigidbody2D rigidbody;
  public bool random;

  // Use this for initialization
  void Start () {
    rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    if (random) {
      rigidbody.velocity = Random.value * transform.right * speed;
    } else {
      rigidbody.velocity = transform.right * speed;
    }
  }
  float angle = 0;
  // Use this for physics calculations
  void FixedUpdate () {
    var wave = Mathf.Sin(angle += waveSpeed); // goes from -1 to +1
    var p = rigidbody.position;
    p.y = wave; // or: yCenter + yHeight * wave
    rigidbody.position = p;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried running your code with different variables but unfortunately could not get the movement i was looking for. I appreciate all of your help though and will have a look at those tutorials you have mentioned. Once i find a solution i will post it here. Thank you